# Image Carousel Failing Unless Refreshed and Weird Redirects with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a jQuery Mobile/Django mobile web app for the first time. There are crazy things happening and I'm pretty sure they can be attributed to jQuery Mobile since I have Django's DEBUG set to True and I'm not getting any errors there and because two of the problems show up on mobile only. Here are the things I've noticed:

1. On mobile only, upon exiting the pop-up that I have at http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/choose_category announcing that the page is a beta version, I'm taken back a page so I can't ever really get to the page I want.
2. On mobile only, when I try to get to the /help_me_decide page from the http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/choose_category page, the URL is changing to http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/choose_category/#/help_me_decide/ instead of just the usual http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/help_me_decide/.
3. On mobile and PC, if I go to the http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/help_me_decide/ page from the http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/help_me_decide/ page, the images don't show up. But if I refresh the /help_me_decide page or open it up with its direct link, the images show up just fine.

Why are these things happening and what can I do about them?

Here are my popup scripts and HTML divs (one is for the normal pages and one is for the /help_me_decide page):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on ( 'pageinit', '#one', function(event) {
setTimeout(function(){
    $( '#popupWelcome' ).popup(); 
    $( '#popupWelcome' ).popup('open'); 
},500);
});

jQuery(document).on ( 'pageinit', '#four', function(event) {
setTimeout(function(){
    $( '#popupDecideOMatic' ).popup(); 
    $( '#popupDecideOMatic' ).popup('open'); 
},500);
});

</script>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupWelcome" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" style="max-width:300px;background-color:#FFFF99;">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <p>Welcome, and thanks for testing <strong>ChiShenMa</strong>!  Please kindly excuse the mess, this is still a work in progress.  Feel free to play around and let us know your feedback!</p>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupDecideOMatic" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" style="max-width:300px;background-color:#FFFF99;">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <p>This is an early test of the <strong>Decide-O-Matic</strong>.  Swipe right if you like a picture and left if you don't.  After 10 swipes, we will match you with the perfect restaurant!</p>
</div>
```

If there's other code I can post that would be useful, please let me know. Here's the whole project: https://github.com/MichelleGlauser/Chishenma/

Comment: 1) add `data-history="false"` to popup's div.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but after closing the popup, the page is still going back to whatever page was open before.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of a popup, it goes to that page where it was initiated from. When popup is closed, page one or four will be active.

Comment: 3) since it's an external page, you have to place any JS code related to that page (four) inside page div, not in head or outside page div. because page is loaded via Ajax and everything outside page div is neglected completely.

Comment: The pop-up is opened on http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/choose_category/, but when I close it, it goes back to google.com or whatever I had opened before I typed in that URL. That's not the default, is it? It should remain on the /choose_category page. Let me check on the other comment.

Comment: When you say "it's an external page," which one are you referring to? When you say "inside page div," do you mean the <div data-role='page'>? Does the popup div need to be inside the <div data-role='page'> as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54399/discussion-between-omar-and-michelle-glauser).

Answer (score 2):

Omar helped me find solutions.

1. He had me set data-history="false" as an attribute in the 'div data-role="page"' and move the popup scripts inside that div.
2. Apparently the URL was only changing in mobile Chrome on iPhone, not in Safari, and it was not a problem because it resolves to the intended URL.
3. I learned how to set the /help_me_decide page ('four') to load via http instead of AJAX by adding 'rel=external' to the anchor for it on the /choose_category page.

Because the popups were flashing and the images on the /help_me_decide page weren't loading, we set up a popup script on pagecontainershow with a Timeout like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if (activePage[0].id == "four") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#popupDecideOMatic").popup().popup("open");
        }, 50);
        $(".slider", activePage).slick();
    }
});
```

But it turned out that the slider was actually already being initialized, so we took out '$(".slider", activePage).slick();' and the images appeared (not sure why they didn't in the first place).

Similar code was used for the /choose_category page:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if (activePage[0].id == "one") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#popupWelcome").popup("open");
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

Comment: Comprehensive answer ;)